# Geometry of the zeros of a power series.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, power-series, roots

This is probably a basic question that is easily googlable, but it seems that I dont have the right keywords. So my question is, having some power series

$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}C_{k}z^{k}, z\in\mathbb{C}, C_{k}\in \mathbb{R}\;\wedge\;C_{0}=1
$$
Is there some theorem relating the coeficients $C_{k}$ of the power series to the geometry of the zeros? More specifically: Is there some theorem implying  that the only zeros of $f(z)$ are **real** zeros if the coefficients $C_{k}$ have some specific properties?

References are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is$C_k$?? $nCr$

Comment: @Archis, $C_{k}\in\mathbb{R}$, are some real coefficients.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but offhand, the question doesn't look tractable. As a starter case, can you answer this for polynomials (possibly of low degree) multiplied by a non-vanishing entire function? For example, can you distinguish $$C_{k} = \frac{1}{k!} \pm \frac{1}{(k-2)!},\qquad k \geq 2,$$and $C_{0} = C_{1} = 1$?

Comment: @Andrew, my intenttion was to have $C_{0}=1$.

Comment: That can always be arranged by dividing through by $C_{0}$, but in any case $C_{0} = 1$ in the proposed test cases (one of which has real zeros and the other of which doesn't). :)